# Django. How to get the object corresponding to a GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

Simple question. I have this model:

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    discount_target = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

How do I get the object the `GenericForeignKey` is pointing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just access it like any other field.

```
my_discount_obj.discount_target
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a special function to get the related object.

```
class Discount(models.Model):
    ....


    def get_related_object(self):
        """
        return the related object of content_type.
        eg: <Question: Holisticly grow synergistic best practices>
        """
        # This should return an error: MultipleObjectsReturned
        # return self.content_type.get_object_for_this_type()
        # So, i handle it with this one:
        model_class = self.content_type.model_class()
        return model_class.objects.get(id=self.object_id)


    @property
    def _model_name(self):
        """
        return lowercase of model name.
        eg: `discount`, `transaction`
        """
        return self.get_related_object()._meta.model_name
```